# levelDB: .sst files are still opened after closing DB

Tags: java, leveldb

I tried to close DB and all opened files generated by it, but `.sst` files are still open.

1. What are `.sst` files? (for LevelDB use)
2. Why do I still see them after I close the DB?
3. Who/what closes them?

I think after a few days running I will get `org.iq80.leveldb.DBException: IO error: Too many open files` exception ultimately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What are .sst files? (for LevelDB use)**
`.sst` is supposed to store your data on disk.

**2. Why do I still see them after I close the DB?**
`leveldb` store files on disk, close the DB only means close the handle to operate it, not delete the data. Like that when you shutdown `mysql` daemon, you didn't really delete the data, you can access it when you restart.

**3. Who/what closes them?**
The process which open the db instance and held the file descriptor of `.sst` files will close them.

As you may care about the problem you proposed in the title, **"levelDB: .sst files are still opened after closing DB"**, normally, the file descriptors will be closed but not the file. If they are still opened, use `lsof` to find out the process opened them.

Answer (score 0):

All sst files would be closed after DB handler was deleted.
But sst files are still on your disk. You can try `DestroyDB` to delete all db files.

You can set `max_open_files` in `Options` to avoid `IO error: Too many open files` when open db.

Comment: thanks!!
but i dont want to delete leveldb files. I want to reopen it .